# iterm2: Multiple simultaneous finds

Tags: iterm

Is there a way to "find" multiple keywords at the same time? Maybe like "keyword1"|"keyword2"

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to search for, the scroll back buffer (output sent to the screen) or files on the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://iterm2.com/documentation-one-page.html):

> When you open the find field (cmd-f) there is a down-arrow on the left of the field by the magnifying glass. Clicking it opens a menu of options in which you can enable regular expression search. The [ICU syntax](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html#regular-expression-metacharacters) is used.

You can then use the syntax:

```
red|blue
```

to find all occurence of the keywords `red` and `blue`.

Note: Tested with iterm2 3.4.23